# jQuery tabs is loaded but not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to work with jQuery UI tabs in WordPress but I keep getting the "jQuery("#").tabs is not a function" error.

I thought the tabs file might not be loading but looking in firebug it shows it is loading. I am also using modernizr so I thought there might be a conflict with that but using jQuery.noConflict(); did not solve the problem either. At first I used  to load jQuery but for some reason it wouldn't work. Now I just linking directly to the files and they are loading.

If it helps, I am trying to get tabs working for [this tutorial](http://legendthemes.com/2010/06/14/building-a-jquery-posts-slider-wordpress/). The website I working on is [lbk.newcoastmedia.com/wordpress](http://lbk.newcoastmedia.com/wordpress)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following scripts being loaded on your page:

```
modernizr-1.6.min.js
l10n.js
jquery.js
galleria.js
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#photo-rotator").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 4000);
});
</script>
```

`$.tabs` is an extension of jQuery UI, and I don't see jQuery UI *or* the tabs extension loaded on your page. Look at the very bottom of the source [at your link](http://demos.legendthemes.com/slider-demo/) and you'll see the following two scripts, which I believe are what you're missing.

```
ui.core.js
ui.tabs.js
```

Your debugger is alerting you that `$.tabs` is not a method because it really hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't loading? Here is a screenshot showing what I get when viewing firebug http://i.imgur.com/pzU7G.png

Comment: Oh, so they're being loaded dynamically then. You're right; I see them in Chrome Console, too. I'm going to see if everything's loading in the right order -- jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery UI widgets, jQuery UI tabs, $(document).ready() -- so I'm thinking the issue is either there or the fact that jQuery's loading twice, once as v1.4.4 and once as v1.6.1.

Comment: Actually, I think you can just solve it by calling `jQuery.noConflict()` or using `$.ui.tabs()`

Comment: Well I already tried noConflict and that didn't work. The thing is, the tutorial is set up as a wp theme. If I install that theme it works just fine but when I copy the code over to my theme it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem on Drupal and resolved it by downloading a custom build of the jQuery UI library WITH Tabs selected. Apparently the default jQuery UI library that shipped with Drupal didn't have this module, so perhaps this is also the case with WP.